# Implicit logarithmic differentiation to find the horizontal tangents of an exponential function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, exponentiation, implicit-differentiation

The graph of $y = 6{(3{x}^2)}^x$ has two horizontal tangent lines. Find equations for both of them.

$$
\\ \begin{align}
\\ y &= 6{(3{x}^2)}^x
\\ y &= 6 \cdot {3}^x \cdot {x}^{2x}
\\ \ln{y} &= \ln{(6 \cdot {3}^x \cdot {x}^{2x})}
\\ \ln{y} &= \ln{6} + \ln{{3}^x} + \ln{{x}^{2x}}
\\ \ln{y} &= \ln{6} + x\ln{3} + 2x\ln{{x}^{2x}}
\\ \frac{d}{dx}[\ln{y}] &= \frac{d}{dx}[\ln{6} + x\ln{3} + 2x\ln{x}]
\\ \frac{y'}{y} &= 0 + \ln{3} + 2\ln{x} + \frac{2x}{x}
\\ y' &= y(2\ln{x} + \ln{3} + 2)
\\ y' &= 6{(3{x}^2)}^x(2\ln{x} + \ln{3} + 2)
\\ 0 &= 6{(3{x}^2)}^x(2\ln{x} + \ln{3} + 2)
\\ \frac{0}{6{(3{x}^2)}^x} &= 2\ln{x} + \ln{3} + 2
\\ 0 &= 2\ln{x} + \ln{3} + 2
\\ -(\ln{3} + 2) &= 2\ln{x}
\\ -\frac{\ln{3} + 2}{2} &= \ln{x}
\\ e^{-\frac{\ln{3} + 2}{2}} &= x
\\ \end{align} 
$$

I've made an error at some point, but I'm not certain what error I'm making.

The $x$ value I've found doesn't appear to satisfy the conditions of the prompt.

Insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
2\ln x+\ln 3 +2 =0 \Rightarrow \ln x^2=-2-\ln 3 \Rightarrow x^2= \dfrac {1}{3e^2}
\Rightarrow x=\pm \dfrac{1}{e \sqrt{3}}
$$

Comment: How do you get to $\frac{1}{3{e}^2}$?

Comment: $e^{-(\ln 3 +2)}=....$

Comment: I don't quite understand how that expression results in the other expression. Could you explain it a bit further?

Comment: exponetiating $\ln x^2=-2-\ln 3$ you have $e^{\ln x^2}=e^{-2-\ln 3} \Rightarrow x^2=e^{-\ln 3} e^{-2}=\dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{1}{e^2}$.

Comment: Ahhh. I see. Grazie tanto!

Comment: Prego!! I'm happy that you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't made a mistake in the answer you found.

$$\exp\left({\frac{-\ln3 - 2}2}\right)= \exp \left({\frac {-\ln 3}2 - \frac 2 2 }\right)$$

$$ = \exp  (-1) \exp \left({\frac {-\ln 3}2}\right)$$

$$ = e^{-1} \left({e^{\ln 3}}\right)^{-1/2}$$

$$ = e^{-1} 3^{-1/2}$$

$$ = \frac 1 {e \sqrt 3} $$

The other answer is missing because you simplified $\ln x^{2x} = 2x \ln x $ instead of the correct $2x \ln |x|$.

edit: unfortunately, these $x$-coordinates aren't the end of your answer, because your assignment asks you to find the equation of the tangent lines at those points!

Comment: I don't quite see how $\frac{-\ln{}3-2}{2}$ begets $\frac{1}{e\sqrt{3}}$. Can you step through it a bit for me? I still have some confusions about $e$.

Comment: @Alex I added some more steps. Does that help?

Comment: Everything's been all cleared up for me. Thanks for the help.